# What are the limitations of the Azure Development Fabric?

Tags: azure, compatibility, appfabric, azure-compute-emulator

I've been reading around and it seems that there are some differences between the dev fabric and a production windows azure cloud fabric but nowhere can I find a list of what is capable on the dev fabric and what isn't compared to the cloud fabric.

For instance, as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803362.aspx):

> All Windows Azure environments in the cloud are the same; there's nothing special about a test or staging area. **However, there are differences between the local development fabric and the cloud fabric**, which is why it's important to test your application in the cloud.

(emphasis mine)

I've seen allusions to these differences in a number of places, but again... nothing saying *what* is different.

Anyone know of any resources that describe these differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) describing specific differences between the Storage emulator and Azure Storage.

And... here's the [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120712004459/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/gg432960.aspx) describing specific differences between the Compute emulator and Windows Azure VM instances.

The top-level article link is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140215051308/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433055.aspx).

Comment: Interestingly, this is a broken link in the MSDN page itself. I just tested the top-level link, which contains a link to the *differences* article, and it's broken there. I'll report it.

Answer (score 5):

David's answer is good, but I want to add that a key difference between the dev fabric and the cloud is that the dev fabric *runs on your computer* (with a bunch of DLLs GAC'd, different settings in IIS, etc.).

Comment: Yup - great point, and a source of many apps that work magically locally but fail to start, once published.